# When zooming an image how can I determine a proper w/h so that I won't get decimals

Tags: algorithm, image, math

Lets say I have a non-square image..

If I increment the width and I recalculate the height according to the incremented width (ratio), sometimes I get xxx.5 (decimals) for the width

ex.: width = 4, height = 2
I augment the width with a factor of 1.25 I'll get : width = 5
Next, the height will be : heigth = 2.5

How can I determine the nearest image format that would have integers on both sides? (bigger if possible)

Thanks

Comment: Thinking of it, I guess both the width and height should be a factor of 'ratio'. Now my question should be, how can I find the lowest common denominator between the width and the height ;) But wikipedia comes handy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_denominator If there's something else, please answer...

Comment: Oups I meant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reduce the fraction to lowest terms and then multiply by integers. You reduce `a/b` to lowest terms by dividing each by their common gcd. If `d = gcd(a,b)`, then `(a/d) / (b/d)` is in lowest terms. Now, if you want the next largest integer fraction with the same ration, then multiple the numerator and denominator by `d+1`. Thus,

`(d+1) * (a/d)` is the numerator and `(d+1) * (b/d)` is the denominator.

Comment: I don't know which to choose ;)

Answer (score 4):

Let g be the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor of w and h. The next biggest image has width w + w/g and height h + h/g. You can compute g with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm .